# Probability of first success.

Tags: probability

A soccer player makes one out of every five shots on average. If we look at independent events, (1) how many shots should we expect him to take before he makes his first goal of a new season. (2) Build a 95% confidence interval.

(1) So far I got the geometric of $(.2)(.8)^{n-1}$, but I'm not sure how to manipulate this.

(2) I could just plug and play for an answer, but I was hoping for a more theoretically sound solution. For example I took $\Pr(X=2,3,..12) = .957$, is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Play comes **first**, then (maybe) theory. If you think about the result of play, you will in this case be able to develop some modest theory. I assume you know how to find a $95\%$ confidence interval by experimentation. If that causes difficulty, I can help with the answer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas could you review my edit to part (2).

Comment: The probability that the number of trials is $\gt k$ is $(0.8)^k$. Solve $(0.8)^k=0.05$. We get, using logs, I think, $13.4$. So $1$ to $14$ puts us under $0.05$. Might check whether $2$ to $14$ does the job.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Doesn't make sense for part (1) to equal 3? If each of the 5 shots are independent, you would expect over time that that shot he makes the goal in out of 5 shots to be evenly distributed. So $(1+2+3+4+5) / 5 = 3$?

Comment: It is possible, and happens quite often, that there are failure streaks quite a bit longer than $5$. So there is no "the" shot out of $5$ that makes it. Actually, the probability that the first successful shot is on the **first** attempt is biggest. But there is a long tail. One can use an argument of your kind for the **median**. In the closely related exponential distribution, the median is quite a bit less than the mean, again the result of the long tail.

Comment: @AndréNicolas You can use a geometric to find a distribution of these tails, but then what formula to you use to find the sweet spot of how many shots we should expect (1)?

Comment: Let $p=0.2$, $q=0.8$. The probability that $X=n$ is $q^{n-1}p$. So $E(X)=\sum_1^\infty nq^{n-1}p$. There are nice "tricks" to evaluate this kind of sum. There are also really quick ways, as described by Hagen von Eitzen. For the **median**, in this case I would just calculate, find the place where the sum of the probabilities shifts from $\lt 1/2$ to $\gt 1/2$. For similar problems but with $p$ much smaller, there are good estimates for the median. But there is no point to them here, calculation is so easy. However, your question asked about the mean.

Answer (score 2):

The naively guessed  answer would be $5$.

And the naive answer is correct. If $E$ is the expected number of shots, then we know that he hits with the first shot with probability $\frac15$, whereas with $\frac45$ we loses the first shot and we start all over again.
Thus
$$ E = \frac15\cdot 1+ \frac45(1+E)$$
which simplifies to 
$$ E=5.$$